# Open file word already in my hdd when click on a link instead of dowload it

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I am learning JS and I was wondering if there is a way to write a script to open the file directly when I click on the link (since it is already on my hdd) instead of download it.
Could you point me in the right direction? 
thanks

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="Moody'sKMVproject-studentsample2.doc" id="aaa"style="color:red">file word</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For security reasons javascript runs in a browser and cannot access local file system.

Comment: At which browsers have you tried code at Question?

Comment: google chrome or firefox